# InvalidCastException was unhandled for C# to use in VB6

Tags: c#, com, vb6

What I'm trying to achieve is slowly modularizing old VB6 code to C#.
I am creating a test in VB6 to press a button and execute my c# form and pass back a string value.
I had it working yesterday and something somehow changed and it no longer works.  Below is my C# code that I'm having the issue.

```
#define USE_COM

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CMS_DB_Operator_Input
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Open the OperatorInput Form
        /// 
        /// Note: Will output the result to console out on success
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">0: The Default Filter to Use</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///     0: Failure to Select
        ///     1: Successfully Selected an Item
        /// </returns>
        [STAThread]
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            string displayName = (args.Length > 1) ? args[1] : null;
            string result = "";
            displayName = "CBU35PN42";
            //displayName = "";

#if USE_COM
            CMS_DB_GateKeeper.IGateKeeperUI api = new MS_DB_GateKeeper.GateKeeperUI();
            result = api.AskOperatorInput(displayName); // <- INVALID CAST EXCEPTION was unhandled
#else
            CMS_DB_GateKeeper.CMS_DB_GateKeeper_OperatorInput op = new CMS_DB_GateKeeper.CMS_DB_GateKeeper_OperatorInput(displayName);
            if (displayName == null)
            {
                Application.Run(op);
                if (op.SelectedDisplayName != null)
                {
                    result = op.GetXmlResult(op.SelectedDisplayName); // Success
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = op.GetXmlResult(displayName);
            }
#endif
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            return 0; 
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Error Picture Goes Here]

Comment: It says "error loading type library", have you verified that the type library is registered?

Comment: To use methods from VB6 in C# you don't need to use COM. Has you already tried to simply import the VB6 dll as reference?

Comment: I'm using it the other way around.  I pulled out some code FROM VB6 and made it C#.  BUT I have to still use this code in VB6.  I"m assuming it is having the problem in my c# code.  Soon as I comment out that one line it executes smoothly, but it doesn't use the function I need it to use, so that I can call it from VB6

Comment: The error indicates an error trying to load the registered type library for the interface whose method will be called with marshaling.  Did you change GUIDs? Did you forgot to unregister the old library (possibly deleted by now) and/or register the new one?

Comment: THANK YOU PAULO! IT worked!! OMG!  I updated the GUID and re-registered the dlls and it is now working.  I'm soo excited!